# Trying to print in c++ OpenGL but an integer is returned?

Tags: c++, opengl, cout

I'm using OpenGL to create a basic user interface and on it I have a help button which opens up a new window. But I am trying to get it to print out something in the output aswell when it's pressed but when I get it to print 'Test' it returns '26729' instead.

Here's the function that is called when the help button is pressed.

```
void Window::helpBut()
{
    cout << 'Test' << endl;  
    m_glWidget->help();
}
```

Can anyone tell me why it won't print 'Test'?

Comment: because you need double quotes `cout << "Test" << endl;`

Comment: I disagree with the votes to close as "a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error." This looks like an issue that others may encounter, and the answer would be useful to them. If this information is available elsewhere at SO, then mark this as a dupe. Otherwise, it should be left open.

Answer (score 4):

tl;dr: Replace your single quotes ' with double quotes "

You're running into one of the more obscure *features* of C/C++ - multi character constants. Their value is implementation defined, but it's syntactically valid to have multiple characters in a character constant. This isn't really useful and you shouldn't ever do it. If you turn on warnings in your compiler you'll be told this is a bad idea.